# Seeming violation of angular momentum conservation

Tags: angular-momentum, home-experiment

[image]

Consider a rod being having a small length hanging over the edge of a table. Suppose an impulsive force is acted on at the tiny portion of length extended over the table then it should produce zero torque at the point where force is applied(*). However, it is still seen that the rod rotates about the point. Why?

How can the angular momentum change without any external torque?

---

*: Force is efficetevly acting at zero distance from the point we are taking moments about

Comment: if the force is really at zero distance from the point, nothing will happen. In an experiment it will be hard really to strike only  or exactly at this point.. Why do you think the angular momentum changes?

Comment: What does the “wh” at the end of the title mean?

Comment: @trula I tried this experiment with a portion of a ruler over hanging a table, it seemed rotate about the end though the force was acting at a very small distance from the point around the point it rotated (exact part over in contact with edge of table)

Comment: @Buraian what does small distance signify . Your small distance can be large enough in physics to produce a torque and rule being light enough is easy to rotate with even a small torque. Moreover hanging signifies something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the force you push, there are other forces on the rod.  There is gravity, and there is the normal force from the table.

As you push down, gravity does not change, but the normal force from the table changes.  It increases and it shifts toward the edge of the table.  Eventually the force increases to the point that the COM will lift up, and the torque from the normal force is no longer countered by gravity and the rod begins to rotate.

Comment: Beautiful answer +1